# I am trying to create a callback in React that would let me pass state from the child to the parent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a callback in React that would let me pass state from the child to the parent. However, I am getting "cbChildToParent: undefined". I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code for the parent:

```jsx
import React from 'react';

import ProjectsHeader from './ProjectsHeader.jsx';
import ProjectsBody from './projectsbodycomponents/ProjectsBody.jsx';

export default class Projects extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
       hidden: false
    };
  }



headerChange(newStateFromHeader)  {
    this.setState({ hidden: newStateFromHeader });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {console.log(this.state.hidden)}
            <section className="projects-background"></section>
            <ProjectsHeader parentToChild={this.state.hidden} cbChildToParent={this.sendToParent} />
            <ProjectsBody />

        </div>
     )
    }
  }
```

Here is my code for the child:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';

import ProjectsHeaderLinks from "./ProjectsHeaderLinks.jsx";

 require('../../../stylesheets/component/projects/ProjectsHeaderLinks.scss');

export default class ProjectsHeader extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        hidden: this.props.parentToChild,
        class: "not-sticky-div",
        class2: "hidden-span",
        class3: "projects-quote-hidden",
        class4: "project-title-hidden"
    }
        console.log(this.props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollTop();
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return this.state.class === "not-sticky-div";
}


componentWillUnmount(){
    $(window).unbind("scroll");
}


    scrollTop(){
        var that = this;
        let head = $(".header");
        let stick = "sticky";
        let projHead = document.getElementById("projHead");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > 400
            ? head.addClass(stick)
            : head.removeClass(stick);
        let newValue = projHead.classList.value.split(' ', 2);
        for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
            newValue[i] === "sticky"
                ? that.setState({hidden: true, class: "sticky-div", class2: "visible-span", class3: "projects-quote", class4: "projects-title"})
                : that.setState({hidden: false, class: "not-sticky-div", class2: "hidden-span", class3: "projects-quote-hidden", class4: "projects-title-hidden"});
        }
    })
}

sendToParent(){
    console.log(this.state.hidden);
    let newStateFromHeader = this.state.hidden;
    this.setState({hidden: newStateFromHeader});
    this.props.cbChildToParent(newStateFromHeader);
}



render() {
    return (
        <div id="projHead" className="header">
            <div className={this.state.class}>
            {this.state.class === "not-sticky-div"
              ? <div>"I love to code" --Lonnie McGill</div>
                : null
            }
            </div>
            <div className={this.state.class3}>
                <div className={this.state.class4}>This is my project page, go ahead and look around.</div>
            </div>
            <ProjectsHeaderLinks state={this.state}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your parent, component, change this:

```jsx
<ProjectsHeader parentToChild={this.state.hidden} cbChildToParent={this.sendToParent} />
```

to:

```jsx
<ProjectsHeader parentToChild={this.state.hidden} cbChildToParent={this.headerChange} />
```

---

You're getting the undefined error because you're trying to reference the method `sendToParent` on the parent class, when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I created the headerChange function to get the callback and then forgot about it.